# Make the button inactive if the input length is 0

Tags: html, vuejs2

I want to make the button not active if text.length <= 0, how do I set its properties and write it in the tag? In Vue js`<button> Add task </button>`

Comment: please provide us with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **not active** means **disabled** then something like this:

```
<button :disabled="!text.length"> Add task </button>
```